# How much training data is needed for a speaker-dependent speech recognition system?

Tags: speech-recognition

To implement a high-accuracy (< 15% WER) speaker-dependent ASR system, how much training data is needed from the speaker?

Also, are speaker-dependent models usually supplemented with a larger corpus of audio (from many speakers)? Or do they only use data from the single speaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To implement a high-accuracy (< 15% WER) speaker-dependent ASR system, how much training data is needed from the speaker?

30-40 hours.

> Also, are speaker-dependent models usually supplemented with a larger corpus of audio (from many speakers)?

Sometimes.

> Or do they only use data from the single speaker?

It is possible to build speaker-dependent speaker from 1-2 hours of speaker data and 300+ hours of data from other speakers. It is less straightforward path than to collect single speaker data.

Comment: If it takes 30-40 hours to train a speaker-dependent system, then how do some apps need only a few example paragraphs of training to work?

Comment: With few paragraphs they adapt generic system to the user, they only slightly improve accuracy, quite far from speaker-dependent system.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Please could you guys direct me to some research these figures come from? I need something to cite. :-)

Comment: I do not think there is such research, it is more a common sense

Answer (score 0):

The answer varies depending on the library you are using.  For embedded voice control systems I have used Sensory's TrulyHandsFree SDK with speaker specific training.  Their process adjusts the recognition network beginning with a speaker independent model and building on that.   To perform reasonably accurate speaker identification requires between 512 and 1024 speaker specific training samples, so something between 45 minutes and 3 hours worth of data.

But if you don't need speaker identification the default models are more than 85% accurate assuming a small grammar size without any speaker specific training.  All of the work I have done has been using relatively small grammars, so speaker identification is the only reason we do speaker specific training.

If you need any sort of unrestricted ASR, then that is outside my area of practice.